# PHP POST data with fwrite and fsockopen

Tags: php, http-post, fwrite, fsockopen

I'm trying to debug this code and have no access actually to the service so only rely on the answer(which send back "ok" plus the list of the parameters transmitted). I check the POST With Z Rest Eazy and it's ok.
Is there any problem with the manner I'm using to give the parameters. (When I try with Poster extension on FF with the same header and parameters it doesn't work either. So Z REst Ezy Ok, AND my code and Poster NG??
Is someone could help?

```
   $post_data = 'nom=nom&prenom=prenom&age=age';

$socket = fsockopen("xx.yyy.zz.aa", 80, $errno, $errstr, 15);    

if(!$socket){    
    echo ' error: ' . $errno . ' ' . $errstr;
    die;
}else{
    $http  = "POST /MyServices/TestProxy HTTP/1.1\r\n";  
    $http .= "Host: xx.yyy.zz.aa:80\r\n";
    $http .= "User-Agent: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\r\n";
    $http .= "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------193612245921106\r\n";
    $http .= "Content-length: " . strlen($post_data) . "\r\n";
    $http .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    $http .= $post_data . "\r\n\r\n";       
    fwrite($socket, $http);     
    $contents = "";     
    while (!feof($socket)) {
        $contents .= fgets($socket, 4096);
    }       
    fclose($socket);
```

With a breakpoint I can see my request which is:

```
POST /MyServices/TestProxy HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.yyy.zz.aa:80
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------193612245921106
Content-length: 29
Connection: close

nom=nom&prenom=prenom&age=age
```

Comment: DO NOT TRY TO WRITE YOUR OWN HTTP CLIENT - PHP's file wrappers and the curl lib are there for a reason. HTTP is *so* much more complicated than just sending bytes down a stream.

Comment: I can't use curl and want to use Troy Wolf http class for a proxy. But As I got same problem I tried another way to found the source of the problem.